# Adding a filter search option using the google api and knockout JS library

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I created an app in which I pulled restaurants and such in a local area using the google API. However I've run into a problem in that I have a list of restaurants and such that are pulled, but I also created a search option and would like to filter my searches.

Below is the code that I have. I have a javascript function, and then my html is listed below.

```
function appViewModel() {
    var self = this; 
    var map;
    var service;
    var infowindow;
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var minnesotaEats = new google.maps.LatLng(44.977753, -93.2650108);
    var markersArray = [];  

    // array to hold info for knockout
    self.allPlaces = ko.observableArray([]);

    // string to hold foursquare information
    self.foursquareInfo = '';

    // Finds the center of the map to get lat and lng values
    function computeCenter() {
      var latAndLng = map.getCenter();
      lat = latAndLng.lat();
      lng = latAndLng.lng(); 
    }

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: minnesotaEats,  
    });

    getPlaces();
    computeCenter();       

    var list = (document.getElementById('list'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(list);

    var input = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));

    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        clearOverlays();
        self.allPlaces.removeAll();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  


        for(var i=0, place; i<10; i++){
           if (places[i] !== undefined){
               place = places[i];

               getAllPlaces(place);
               createMarker(place);
               bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);          
           }        
        } 
        map.fitBounds(bounds); 
        computeCenter();                
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });   

}

  /*
Function to pre-populate the map with place types.  nearbySearch retuns up to 20 places.
*/

function getPlaces() {
  var request = {
    location: minnesotaEats,
    radius: 600,
    types: ['restaurant', 'bar', 'cafe', 'food']
  };

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);    
}
```

Index.html

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Location">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="list">
    <h2>Great places to eat in Minneapolis!</h2>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: allPlaces">
        <li data-bind="click: $parent.clickMarker"> 
            <hr>               
            <p class="name"><span data-bind="text: name"><span></p> 
            <p class="address"><span data-bind="text: address"></span></p>                
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Repo: https://github.com/Jstein1313/Project-5---Neighborhood-Map

Comment: Please show your search function and knockout VM

Comment: @Matt.k thanks, updated it.

Comment: Your javascript code example is not complete... it ends with " serv"

Comment: Please correct indentations as well. It would be great if you could provide a jsffidle of code

Comment: @kabaehr Sorry about that, updated it.

Comment: @Matt.k I tried to make one, but it doesn't display the Google Maps API. I've added a link to the actual repo: https://github.com/Jstein1313/Project-5---Neighborhood-Map